# Spring Web Flux React front end with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-webflux

I'm new to spring web flux react technologies but following a tutorial I got to develop my first "hello world" service. Now I'm trying to connect with this service using angularjs 1.5.9 as front end library.

The issue is I cannot found an example, library or module to use for calling this simple service using AngularJS. All examples are related to AngularJS 2.

Does anyone know any module?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no AngularJS expert but as of [Spring 5.0 M5](https://spring.io/blog/2017/02/23/spring-framework-5-0-m5-update), Spring WebFlux can emit Flux using `text/event-stream` formatted as [Server-Sent Event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) (SSE). Any client that's able to understand this kind of formatting can consume the stream coming from a Spring WebFlux application.

Furthermore, clients can also request Content-Type to be `application/stream+json` and the response will be a stream of JSON objects similar to Server-Sent Events but without the extra formatting.

Here are some extra resources:

- [AngularJS with Server-Sent Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166770)
- [Angular using Server Sent Events in a factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131691)
- [HTML5: Server-sent events with Angular.js, Node.js and Express.js](https://dzone.com/articles/html5-server-sent-events)

And this library is worth checking out: [angular-oboe](https://github.com/RonB/angular-oboe)

A possible implementation found [here](https://github.com/mastbaum/tiny-angularjs-sse-example/blob/master/index.html), suggests that consuming SSE from an AngularJS application can be as simple as:

```
angular.module('foo', []).factory('sse', function($rootScope) {
  var sse = new EventSource('/stream');
  return {
    addEventListener: function(eventName, callback) {
      sse.addEventListener(eventName, function() {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(sse, args);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});

function FooCtrl($scope, sse) {
  $scope.foos = [];
  sse.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    $scope.foos.push({value: e.data});
  });
}
```